# How do I go through the while loop until I get n=0 and add up the cost of each layer to give me the total cost? AKA. adding the cost of each iteration

Tags: python

```
def get_pizza_cake_cost(base_diameter, height_per_level):
    n = base_diameter
    while n > 0:
        cost = get_pizza_area(n) * height_per_level * PIZZA_CAKE_COST_PER_CENTIMETRE_CUBED
        n = n - 1
    return cost
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg0mH.png)

if you look at the shell here, i would like the function to return the sum of those two values

Comment: In your loop `cost += get_pizza_area(n) * height_per_level * PIZZA_CAKE_COST_PER_CENTIMETRE_CUBED`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the existing line to
`cost += get_pizza_area(n) * height_per_level * PIZZA_CAKE_COST_PER_CENTIMETRE_CUBED`

```
    def get_pizza_cake_cost(base_diameter, height_per_level):
        n = base_diameter
        while n > 0:
            cost += get_pizza_area(n) * height_per_level * PIZZA_CAKE_COST_PER_CENTIMETRE_CUBED
            n = n - 1
        return cost
```

Comment: i dont have enough rep for it to show but i did!

Answer (score 0):

well, it does not necessarily depend on your data type, but it helps depict better, your situation. Example: for an array of ints that represent cost n = 10: ->

```
sum = 0;
while (n>0){
    sum += arr[n];
    n -= 1;
}
return sum;
```

Comment: The question asked for a solution in Python, not Java.

Comment: New to the site and I did not initially recognize that. Either way, Python and Java would implement this the same way, but they have different syntax. It is a while loop, any high level programming language would implement a basic counting while loop the same way, but with different syntax.